# Whether to connect to the database in the javascript getter

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to utilize JavaScript to construct an object that has a property, utilizing a getter method to retrieve data from the database every time it is invoked.

The actual working code is shown below, however, the multi-connection database aspect is not covered. Having done that, I'm not sure how accurate it is, as the resources referenced during the implementation didn't cover this specific aspect. This leads to some confusion about the difference between attributes and behavior

```
class Article {
  constructor(info) {
    this._id = info.id;
    this._content = info.content;
  }

  get content() {
    return (async () => {
      try {
        const query = { id: this._id };
        const artData = await ArticleModel.findOne(query);
        return artData.content;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    })();
  }
......
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What's the relationship between `content` and `_content`?

Comment: Avoid doing heavy stuff like database calls in getters.

Comment: Sorry, after reading the guide, I edited and revised the text content as soon as possible.

Comment: Async getters is bad practice.

Comment: content and _content are the results of modification after encountering problems during implementation. When both are content, node js will display an error message.

Comment: @eruc - Right, you can't assign to an accessor property that has no setter. But that doesn't explain what the relationship is meant to be. Are they meant to be the same thing? But then, why the data retrieval on access if you already have the data from the constructor?

Comment: ＠ T.J. Crowder
 Yes, they are referring to the same concept. The reason for performing a data search every time is because in the future, the information may only be available as an ID, requiring the reassignment of the object's attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...utilizing a getter method to retrieve data from the database every time it is invoked

If it's going to do the retrieval every time it's accessed, I would suggest **not** making it a getter. That's behavior for a method, not an accessor property.

Re the `try`/`catch` in your code: In general, allow errors to propagate rather than handling them too early. That `try`/`catch` is definitely too early, the calling code should have a chance to know the promise has been rejected, rather than what the code above is doing, which is converting rejection into fulfillment with `undefined`.

```
class Article {
    constructor(info) {
        this._id = info.id;
        this._content = info.content;
    }

    async getContent() {
        const query = { id: this._id };
        const artData = await ArticleModel.findOne(query);
        return artData.content;
    }
}
```

---

**If** you were going to make this an accessor property instead, then it shouldn't start a new request every time it's accessed. Instead, save the promise and reuse it:

```
class Article {
    #dataPromise = null;

    constructor(info) {
        this._id = info.id;
        this._content = info.content;
    }
 
    get content() {
        if (!this.#dataPromise) {
            this.#dataPromise = (async () => {
                const query = { id: this._id };
                const artData = await ArticleModel.findOne(query);
                return artData.content;
            })();
        }
        return this.#dataPromise;
    }
}
```

Or equivalently:

```
class Article {
    #dataPromise = null;

    constructor(info) {
        this._id = info.id;
        this._content = info.content;
    }

    get content() {
        if (!this.#dataPromise) {
            const query = { id: this._id };
            this.#dataPromise = ArticleModel.findOne(query)
                .then((artData) => artData.content);
        }
        return this.#dataPromise;
    }
}
```

But again, I wouldn't use an accessor property for this. I'd use a method.